# gRPC interceptor to generate default responses

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm looking at a way to implement a Java gRPC interceptor which, instead of making the actual call to the server, returns the default instance for that response type. I believe this can be implemented either as a client interceptor or server interceptor, but client makes more sense to avoid a network hop. But in either case, the application server should not see any request on its side, i.e. short-circuit the request handling.

```java
public class GrpcClientRequestInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

  public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(
      final MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> methodDescriptor,
      final CallOptions callOptions,
      final Channel channel) {

    // The client should always return RespT.getDefaultInstance()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The client interceptor approach makes sense here. In `interceptCall()` you want to return a `ClientCall` that only produces the default instance. Your implementation would implement the `start()` method and there call the `onMessage()` method of the `ClientCall.Listener` that gets passed in.

One thing to be aware of is the use of the right `Executor`. Check the `CallOptions` provided to `interceptCall()` to see if an executor is set (`CallOptions.getExecutor()`) and use it if so. If there is no executor you can use a direct executor (`ManagedChannelBuilder.directExecutor()`).

I hope that helps!